# How to put a keyframe on render visibility through python on blender

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, bezier-curves, keyframes

I'm trying to automate an application that involves a lot of objects appearing and disappearing, then a thought in using python to do this bot I don't know the specific command to create a keyframe for the viewport render, somebody help me please

By the way, what I trying to do is creating a bezier curve that can moves, so I'm thinking in create a sphere in every point of the curve and then move the spheres, make it pop ups and so on, something like that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVwxzDHniEw

Answer (score 1):

This line will set a keyframe on visibility for an object called "Torus" at keyframe 1:

```py
bpy.data.objects['Torus'].keyframe_insert("hide_render", frame=1)
```

So, if you wanted to change this to something more generic, the steps are:

- Select the object you want to hide
- Set its `hide_render` value to `True` or `False`
- Select the frame number you want the keyframe on
- enter a statement like the above.

If I wanted to keyframe the value to `True` on the active object at frame 17:

```py
bpy.context.active_object.hide_render = True
bpy.context.active_object.keyframe_insert("hide_render", frame=17)
```